# How can I see the battery status of my Logitech wireless mouse?

Tags: mouse, battery, logitech, logitech-unifying

Is there a way to monitor the mouse's battery status in Kubuntu? I have a [Logitech Wireless Mouse M510](http://www.logitech.com/it-it/product/wireless-mouse-m510) and in Windows I can use the default software (from official site) to monitor battery status and do other things like editing some mouse buttons etc.

Is there any software to do same thing or just monitoring battery status (applets, widgets, software etc.)?

Comment: It appears that only half a year ago some first work was done to get this information through the HID USB interface in the Linux kernel. See [this wonderful article](http://julien.danjou.info/blog/2012/logitech-k750-linux-support) if you're interested in technical background. (not an answer, so posting a comment)

Comment: More specifically, only since June 2012 it's known how the HID++ protocol Logitech uses actually works. This protocol has been released into the public, so it's just a matter of time for this to be included in Ubuntu. [Logitech HID++ specification document](http://6xq.net/git/lars/lshidpp.git/plain/doc/logitech_hidpp_2.0_specification_draft_2012-06-04.pdf) - it includes *"0x1000 Battery Unified Level Status"*

Comment: Would love this for the Logitech G703 as well. [libratbag/piper considered this](https://github.com/libratbag/piper/issues/222) but they appear to be deferring to GNOME for now.

Answer (score 38):

From the CLI, [UPower](https://upower.freedesktop.org/) can do this:

```
$ upower --dump
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/mouse_0000o0000o0000x0000
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9.4/3-9.4:1.2/0000:0000:0000.0000/0000:0000:0000.0000
  vendor:               Logitech, Inc.
  model:                Anywhere MX
  serial:               00000000
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Sun 10 Jul 2016 04:47:36 AM EDT (84 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  mouse
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          95%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
[...]
```

From the GUI, `mate-power-statistics` (from the MATE Power Manager project) or [`gnome-power-statistics`](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-power-manager/stable/statistics.html.en) (from the GNOME Power Manager project) can do this.

[image: gnome power statistics]

Comment: Does not work with my Logitech G900 :-(

Comment: How do you get so many data points? At the largest 'data length' it shows only 2 data points for my mouse (one at a time my PC was in stand-by!?) and none at all for my battery. It seems it doesn't record in the background like it should be.

Comment: Does not work for Logitech G Pro Wireless.

Comment: works for my G903 with Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks upower people for fixing it!!!!

Answer (score 14):

Using the Solaar program as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/285604/6969), you can obtain the battery status.

[image: Screenshot of Solaar]

---

*warning: technical gibberish below, feel free to skip if you are not interested in hacking this mouse*

The M510 is a HID++ 1.0 device judging from the register dump at the [Solaar repository](https://github.com/pwr/Solaar/blob/master/docs/devices/m510.txt). The HID++ 2.0 document that include *Battery Unified Level Status* as linked by gertvdijk are irrelevant here.

As noted on https://git.lekensteyn.nl/ltunify/tree/registers.txt, the "07" register shows the battery status. If you want to learn more about the technical side, you can read [my article about reverse engineering the protocol](https://lekensteyn.nl/logitech-unifying.html).

Comment: hi, I have one logitech recevier and both my M150 and my logitech keyboard are connected to it, but the solaar program only recognizes the keyboard and it doesn't find the M150

Comment: it's not paired that's the problem.  btw it can't find the command solaar show: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/72f58a989bdf4d3f92e3

Comment: the problem is that it does not recognize the mouse, I tried to pair it with no success.

Comment: With either program? To pair, you must start the pairing proces and have your mouse (M510, not the wired M150 right?) powered off. Then turn it back on and the pairing proces should be complete. Are you sure there is sufficient battery in the mouse? Isn't there a second receiver plugged into another machine? What keyboard do you have and what receiver is it? Unifying, Nano or something else? (please answer all questions, that saves me from repeating them)

Comment: the pairing process doesn't work with solaar, I did not try ltunify. I have M510. I have tried to turn if off and then turn it on (many times). The is sufficient battery. There is only one receiver but it is used for both mouse and keyboard, solaar program only recognizes my keyboard logitech K360. it's a logitech receiver.

Comment: Can you give ltunify a go? See https://lekensteyn.nl/logitech-unifying.html#ltunify List devices using `ltunify list`, pair a new device with `ltunify pair`.

Comment: Does not work for Logitech G Pro Wireless mouse.

Answer (score 7):

You can go to your power settings. There you will hopefully have the battery left of any device that runs on batteries.

In my distro (Mint) I can see the battery remaining of my laptop and my mouse by clicking in the power icon at the status bar (bottom-right).

I can also go to *power management*, and there is a "Batteries" tab, and there it is too.

I don't know if this is available in all distros, but it is so easy to check that there's no harm in giving it a try.

Comment: I can see my mouse (Logitech M705) battery level by default from a similar place in elementary OS (0.4, Loki). The thing is that I am not sure the battery level shown is correct. It has been 100% for several weeks now.

Comment: @MagnusTeekivi Late reply, and by now you probably already know how little battery that mouse uses. I have the same and still haven't changed the battery after 3+ years. So, yeah, I think 100% for the first few weeks sounds reasonable

Answer (score 2):

Search "power" in the GUI and pull up power statistics. Click mouse on the left, the default will be the laptop battery. Note this will not work if the battery is already dead (as I just learned).