# How to change Function (Fn) Key behavior on wireless Logitech keyboard

Tags: wireless, keyboard, shortcut-keys, logitech, logitech-unifying

I do have a wireless Logitech K750 keyboard (silver Mac version) connected to a Lenovo ThinkPad (via the unifying USB receiver, together with a wireless Logitech mouse M705) and currently running Ubuntu 12.04.

By default the F-keys are mapped as multimedia/function keys, e.g. <kbd>Play</kbd>  /<kbd>Pause</kbd>. As I don't use them very often, I want the F-keys to behave like the "real" F-keys (<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>). How can I do that?

I know there is an option in the BIOS settings, but this only toggles the built-in keyboard of the notebook, not on my wireless keyboard.

I know there is a way to change this for the Apple wireless keyboard ([AppleKeyboard#Change_Function_Key_behavior](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Change_Function_Key_behavior)), but there is no "parameters" directory in /sys/module/hid_logitech_dj/.

Any ideas? Or is there maybe a way to do this in a later Ubuntu version (13.04)?

UPDATE:

`lsusb -d 046d:` shows
`Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver`

UPDATE 2:
Thanks a lot for your help Lekensteyn. Finally [Solaar](https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/) works just fine. In the "Known Issues" of Solaar it says that it does not work with the Nano Receiver. But I have one and it works just fine. Just don't forget to read the installation instructions and run the `rules.d/install.sh` script. It also recognized my M705 Mouse.

Comment: I just found https://github.com/pwr/Solaar, it looks like it able to toggle FN keys.

Comment: According to the lsusb output, you really have a Unifying device, not a nano receiver. Do you see the Unifying icon on the receiver?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Solaar](https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/) is a graphical utility that has the ability to configure the Fn key functionality on newer devices:

[image: Solaar screenshot with Fn function swap configuration]

Since Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid), Solaar can be installed from the repositories (`sudo apt-get install solaar`). After installation, you can search for *Solaar* in the applications menu and start it from there.

A command line interface is also available. Example usage:

```
$ solaar show
...
  2: Wireless Illuminated Keyboard K800
...
$ solaar config 2
fn-swap = False
$ solaar config 2 fn-swap on
fn-swap = True
```

Note that these settings are not persistent, you will loose it after reboot. This may change in future versions of Solaar.

---

I have previously created the `ltunify` tool which is a Unifying tool that is able to communicate in the older HID++ 1.0 protocol. Until the next version of Solaar is released (current version is 0.8.7), you can use `ltunify` to toggle the Fn key on an older device such as the K800 keyboard.

Installation instructions (taken from https://askubuntu.com/a/114089/6969):

```
sudo apt-get install git gcc
git clone https://git.lekensteyn.nl/ltunify.git -b fkeyswap
cd ltunify
make install-home
```

The command `ltunify fkeyswap` shows the current status:

```
$ sudo ltunify fkeyswap 
F key functions are not swapped
```

To swap the functionality, run `ltunify fkeyswap on`:

```
$ sudo ltunify fkeyswap on
F key functions are now swapped
```

There is also an `off` action:

```
$ sudo ltunify fkeyswap off
F key functions are now normal
```

Please leave a comment if it does not work so it can be fixed. The above functionality uses undocumented hardware registers.

Comment: Solaar failed for me as reported at: https://github.com/pwr/Solaar/issues/162. Also it is in my PATH so I can do just `solaar -V`.

Comment: I tried `ltunify` as you described, but the command `sudo ltunify fkeyswap` outputs this message: `Unable to check fkey status`. I checked that the devices is correctly connected and paired.

Comment: @MichalVician Newer devices use a different protocol version, try [Solaar](https://github.com/pwr/Solaar) instead to control the FN keys. If the `solaar` package from the repos does not work, try the master branch which has many more fixes and features.

Comment: solaar installed via pip (not the debian-packaged version) worked for me with the "K400 Plus" model. example: `solaar config 1 fn-swap off`.

Comment: This software worked perfectly on Linux Mint 20 from the repository. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

You no longer need a `ppa` to install this in Ubuntu 15.08 wily.  Just type

```
sudo apt-get install solaar
```

at the command line.

Additionally, if you are using Unity or Gnome Shell, you can use the following command instead:

```
sudo apt-get install solaar-gnome
```

Comment: Works perfectly with K400+ and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It required solaar package only. Open solaar with usb receiver unplugged. Plug it in. Use "Swap Fx function". Ready.

Answer (score 4):

For wired keyboard like k290 use https://github.com/milgner/k290-fnkeyctl
and execute command

```
/usr/local/sbin/k290_fnkeyctl
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: this is link to program for doing this, use this program for swap FN keys.

Comment: This work for K290 Keyboard on Ubuntu Vivid 15/04

Comment: Still works for a K290 on Focal 20.04

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's frowned upon to answer an 9 year old question, but this information really helped me with my wireless logitech keyboard and it might be useful for someone else, I heard it works on most logitech wireless keyboards, no software needed:

```
Press esc + fn on the keyboard and it switches between modes
```

Comment: Just reporting that the K780 does not support this

Comment: K400 doesn't support this, either.

Comment: Works for me for Logitech MX Mini Keys keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I use a Bluetooth keyboard Logitech K480. For me, solaar didn't work as it was unable to find a Logitech receiver. However, this configuration utility on GitHub worked flawlessly.

[K480 Conf - Github](https://github.com/embuc/k480_conf)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference, as link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes