# How can I change the functionality of the keys on my Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: wireless, keyboard, shortcut-keys, virtualization

I got a HP 255 G2 laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to change the functionality of the F2,F3,F4,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11 and F12 because F2 and F3 are used for changing the luminosity,the others are for volume,wireless switch on/off etc. so they are mostly useless and when I tried to install a UNIX Virtual machine,I had to press F12 and I just turned off the wifi or on Minecraft I couldn't save a seed or toggle view because of this...I'm sorry if it isn't the right site to ask this but I thought that maybe the operating system matters.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285512/how-to-change-function-fn-key-behavior-on-wireless-logitech-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can ask this question on this site. :)

You can do this:
1. Open up `System Settings`.
2. Choose `Keyboard`.
3. Go to the tab `Shortcuts`.
4. Remove any shortcuts you do not want.

This may not work for the WiFi key though.

#### EDIT

You could also try seeing if there's an option in the BIOS to change them. When you start your computer, at the very first screen where it says your manufacturer logo (HP), it should say something like `F2 to enter setup`. Press F2 at that time and it should take you into BIOS (which is a fancy name for the hardware options of your computer). There might be some options in there to disable fn keys.

Comment: I tried it,but I couldn't find the shortcuts I wanna disable...Any other options?

Comment: I know what is the BIOS (Basic Imput-Output System),but it seems that many of those settings are locked,I saw it when I tried to overclock my CPU...Probably I'll try it but at the moment I'm using a secondary keyboard.I searched on google how to unlock them and I found some software for Windows :( that are supposed to be able to do this,do you know any post or site for doing it on Linux,especially Ubuntu?

Comment: Locked? You mean by a password?

Comment: No,I simply couldn't make any modification to them...

Comment: I've read that some BIOS firmwares have a safety feature where you can only change some settings with the `+` and `-` keys. Have you tried that by chance? I've also read that only the keys on the number pad work for this.