# How to switch/disable functionality of fn keys on Ubuntu - USB keyboard

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, function-keys

Hi I have a problem with my new USB Lenovo keyboard, I can't (don't know how) switch <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys in Linux, [on windows it was very easy](http://blog.lenovo.com/en/blog/switching-function-keys-to-standard-f1-f12-on-lenovo-slim-usb-keyboard).

But I don't know what I can do on Linux to switch <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys (or disable), do you know any solution? I need standard functions of <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd>...

Comment: Try pressing fn + Esc.

Comment: Do you mean the key with the label `Fn`, or the 12 keys with 12 different labels `Fn` with `n` being one of 1 to 12? What exactly do you want the keys to do?

Comment: @Zacharee1
I tried, it doesnt work

Comment: @Volker Siegel
I mean 12 keys (additional functionality of F1-11), now when I press F1 then i mute sound, i have to press Fn key and F1... I want to primary function of F1 was F1 not mute, F2 not volume down, etc...

And the question is how to switch that functionality (as an example i gave you link with solution for windows) or disable all Fn functions (mute, volume down, volume up...)

Comment: So you want to have to press `fn` before you press `F1-12` for it to function as a shortcut key?

Comment: Did you check http://askubuntu.com/questions/285512/how-to-change-function-fn-key-behavior-on-wireless-logitech-keyboard  - or other questions listed as "related" to the right?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I want to press fn only when i would use additional functionality of that keys

Comment: @Volker Siegel i saw that, but solaar is program for Logitech keyboard only...

Comment: have you got it working ?

Comment: For my Cherry MX 10 Keyboard, FN+CTRL helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a software solution.

clone the following program from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/lentinj/tp-compact-keyboard.git
```

compile to following program:

```
cd tp-compact-keyboard/tp-compact-usb-keyboard
make
sudo ./tp-compact-usb-keyboard /dev/hidraw1
```

Maybe some errors are shown when you execute the program.

This program sent 2 keystrokes to the keyboard (0x05 and 0x01).

i think, you can't press them physically:

http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html

They are mapped to special keys.

this is only a temporary solution - after a reboot this settings are gone.

maybe you create a cronjob to fix it permanently:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/

Comment: PS: 
Model-No: SK-8821
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17ef:6018 Lenovo

Comment: same keyboard, also works for me! +1 :)

Comment: Worked for Lenovo SK-8821 in Xubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 39):

[image]

this is the best solution what i found ;-)

Comment: You will be happy to know that there is someone else with the exact same solution out there :D Thanks for the pic, I was starting to think of which small heavy object I could use to keep this key pressed. All that for a keyboard of very average quality...

Comment: Did you do the FN+ESC trick?

Comment: FN+ESC will only work directly on the laptop not this keyboard, the keyboard miss also on/off switch I think the developer of this keyboard was fool.

Comment: "Smart" engineers from lenovo broke that solution. Now the Fn key is between control and windows keys on the left of space bar. A paper blocker or heavy object are definitely a no go at that place. Actually putting the Fn key there is really awkward because it's very easy to mistake it with Windows key. I'm considering buying another (non lenovo) keyboard :-(

Comment: solaar installed via pip worked for me with the "K400 Plus" model. example: `solaar config 1 fn-swap off`

Comment: solaar doesn't work for Lenovo SK-8821, it looks like this tools is intended to be used with Logitech devices