# I have a microsoft wireless mouse. Can I somehow see the battery status?

Tags: wireless, mouse, battery

Is there a software that can do that? I searched through the internet and couldn't find a thing.

Comment: Could you include the *exact* mouse model number? If your mouse is HID++ 2.0 compliant like newer Logitech mice, then it will be possible to read the battery status. See also http://askubuntu.com/a/287992/88802

Comment: I forgot to mention I had already seen that thread and it didn't work on my mouse. It's a Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct battery status viewer. Just with the help of Voltmeter.

Comment: For Logitech devices you can. [How can I see the battery status of my Logitech wireless mouse?](http://askubuntu.com/q/248006/88802) Could you provide a source that one cannot do the same for Microsoft wireless HID++ 2.0 mice?