# How can I check battery percentage in Razer Mamba Wireless 2018 in command line?

Tags: command-line, wireless, mouse, battery

I have recently bought the Razer Mamba Wireless (2018) mouse. I would like to check the battery status (percentage) of the mouse in command line ?

Is is possible and how can I do this?

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1532:0072 Razer USA, Ltd
```

```
$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Wireless Receiver       id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Wireless Receiver Consumer Control  id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
    ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Wireless Receiver Keyboard  id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Wireless Receiver       id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Wireless Receiver System Control    id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Mamba Wireless Receiver Consumer Control  id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways.  One is to use the command

`inxi -B`

You will probably need to `sudo apt instal inxi` first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer unfortunately the command shows: `Battery:   Message: No system battery data found. Is one present?`

Comment: Sorry - I misread your question, and assumed you were looking for the battery of the computer

Comment: There is an answer using `upower` [at this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/796931/283721)